# Is there any difference in using subprocess.check_output() in Windows and OS X?

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to use `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)` to execute `cmd` in Windows. It turns out that there is no output after executing this statement, but it works in OS X. I want to know if there is some problem when using `shell=True`. Here's my original source.

```
paper_name = sheet[location].value
name = '"' + paper_name + '"'
cmd = py + options + name + ' -t'
out_str = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)
pdb.set_trace()
#a = out_str.split('\n')
fp_str = to_str(out_str)
a = fp_str.split('\n')
```

cmd is like below
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35VR0.jpg)

Comment: Please include the repr of `cmd`.

Comment: You should probably be passing a list, not a string, as the first argument to `check_output`. It tends to handle lists properly... strings, not so much. You probably want something like `subprocess.check_output([py, options, name, '-t'], shell = True)`, although if you pass in multiple options you should break those up... one string in the list per option.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, never pass a list when using `shell=True`.

Comment: @eryksun - I've never heard that before. Why not?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, in Unix a command-line string is used because the command needs to be a single argument to `sh -c`. The rest of the arguments will be passed as shell parameters, e.g. try `subprocess.call(['echo $0 $1', 'spam', 'eggs'], shell=True)`. In Windows, `subprocess.list2cmdline` converts an argument list to a command-line string based on the rules VC++ uses to parse the command line into an `argv` array. But the CMD shell follows different rules (e.g. CMD's escape character is "^").

Comment: @eryksun  the repr of cmd has been included,but i'm not sure if it concerns about the args of check_output.

Comment: Why are you trying to start one Python instance from another? Couldn't you just import whatever functions you want to use and run them? Then you don't need to worry about passing your arguments from Python to the shell then back into another Python process.